# How can I prevent my Ackerman function from overflowing the stack?

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow

Is there a way to keep my Ackerman function from creating a stack over flow is does it for relatively small numbers ,  i.e. (4,2).  This is the error

> {Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack
>   overflow state.}

```
private void  Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var t = Ackermann(4,2);
            label1.Text += string.Format(": {0}", t);
            label1.Visible = true;
        }

        int Ackermann(uint m, uint n)
        {
            if (m == 0)
                return  (int) (n+1);
            if (m > 0 && n == 0)
                return Ackermann(m - 1, 1);
            if (m > 0 && n > 0)
                return Ackermann(m - 1, (uint)Ackermann(m, n - 1));
            else
            {
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Which line does the stack overflow occur at? Also, have you seen: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#C.23

Comment: Seems to be an expected result http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function **Its value grows rapidly, even for small inputs. For example A(4,2) is an integer of 19,729 decimal digits**

Comment: Oh my... http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Ackerman%284%2C+2%29

Comment: You could keep track of the recursion depth and have the code apologize profusely if it exceeds a set limit.  It's not an error, it's a feature.

Comment: Anyone know the closed-form expression for the Ackerman function?

Comment: What's with the "not a real question"? They've got a method that throws an exception for valid input, and they want it to not throw that exception. How more straightforward can you get?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The best way to avoid `StackOverflowException` is to not use the stack.

Let's get rid of the negative case, as it's meaningless when we call with `uint`. Alternatively, what follows here will also work if we make the negative test the very first thing in the method, before the other possibilities are considered:

First, we're going to need a bigger boat:

```
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
        if (m == 0)
            return  n+1;
        if (n == 0)
            return Ackermann(m - 1, 1);
        else
            return Ackermann(m - 1, Ackermann(m, n - 1));
    }
```

Now success is at least mathematically possible. Now, the `n == 0` case is a simple enough tail-call. Let's eliminate that by hand. We'll use `goto` because it's temporary so we don't have to worry about velociraptors or Dijkstra:

```
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
    restart:
        if (m == 0)
            return  n+1;
        if (n == 0)
        {
            m--;
            n = 1;
            goto restart;
        }
        else
            return Ackermann(m - 1, Ackermann(m, n - 1));
    }
```

This will already take a bit longer to blow the stack, but blow it, it will. Looking at this form though, note that `m` is never set by the return of a recursive call, while `n` sometimes is.

Extending this, we can turn this into an iterative form, while only having to deal with tracking previous values of `m`, and where we would return in the recursive form, we assign to `n` in our iterative form. Once we run out of `m`s waiting to be dealt with, we return the current value of `n`:

```
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
        Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
        stack.Push(m);
        while(stack.Count != 0)
        {
            m = stack.Pop();
            if(m == 0)
                n = n + 1;
            else if(n == 0)
            {
                stack.Push(m - 1);
                n = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                stack.Push(m - 1);
                stack.Push(m);
                --n;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

At this point, we have answered the OP's question. This will take a long time to run, but it will return with the values tried (m = 4, n = 2). It will never throw a `StackOverflowException`, though it will end up running out of memory above certain values of `m` and `n`.

As a further optimisation, we can skip adding a value to the stack, only to pop it immediately after:

```
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
        Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
        stack.Push(m);
        while(stack.Count != 0)
        {
            m = stack.Pop();
        skipStack:
            if(m == 0)
                n = n + 1;
            else if(n == 0)
            {
                --m;
                n = 1;
                goto skipStack;
            }
            else
            {
                stack.Push(m - 1);
                --n;
                goto skipStack;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

This doesn't help us with stack nor meaningfully with heap, but given the number of loops this thing will do with large values, every bit we can shave off is worth it.

Eliminating `goto` while keeping that optimisation is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Incidentally, I got too impatient in testing this, so I did a cheating form that uses known properties of the Ackerman function when m is less than 3:

```
    public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
    {
        Stack<BigInteger> stack = new Stack<BigInteger>();
        stack.Push(m);
        while(stack.Count != 0)
        {
            m = stack.Pop();
        skipStack:
            if(m == 0)
                n = n + 1;
            else if(m == 1)
                n = n + 2;
            else if(m == 2)
                n = n * 2 + 3;
            else if(n == 0)
            {
                --m;
                n = 1;
                goto skipStack;
            }
            else
            {
                stack.Push(m - 1);
                --n;
                goto skipStack;
            }
        }
        return n;
    }
```

With this version, I can get a result of `true` for `Ackermann(4, 2) == BigInteger.Pow(2, 65536) - 3` after a little over a second (Mono, Release build, running on a Core i7). Given that the non-cheating version is consistent in returning the correct result for such values of `m`, I take this as reasonable evidence of the correctness of the previous version, but I'll leave it running and see.

Edit: Of course, I'm not really expecting the previous version to return in any sensible timeframe, but I thought I'd leave it running anyway and see how its memory use went. After 6 hours it's sitting nicely under 40MiB. I'm pretty happy that while clearly impractical, it would indeed return if given enough time on a real machine.

Edit: Apparently it's being argued that `Stack<T>` hitting its internal limit of 2³¹ items counts as a sort of "stack overflow", too. We can deal with that also if we must:

```
public class OverflowlessStack <T>
{
    internal sealed class SinglyLinkedNode
    {
        //Larger the better, but we want to be low enough
        //to demonstrate the case where we overflow a node
        //and hence create another.
        private const int ArraySize = 2048;
        T [] _array;
        int _size;
        public SinglyLinkedNode Next;
        public SinglyLinkedNode()
        {
            _array = new T[ArraySize];
        }
        public bool IsEmpty{ get{return _size == 0;} }
        public SinglyLinkedNode Push(T item)
        {
            if(_size == ArraySize - 1)
            {
                SinglyLinkedNode n = new SinglyLinkedNode();
                n.Next = this;
                n.Push(item);
                return n;
            }
            _array [_size++] = item;
            return this;
        }
        public T Pop()
        {
            return _array[--_size];
        }
    }
    private SinglyLinkedNode _head = new SinglyLinkedNode();

    public T Pop ()
    {
        T ret = _head.Pop();
        if(_head.IsEmpty && _head.Next != null)
            _head = _head.Next;
        return ret;
    }
    public void Push (T item)
    {
        _head = _head.Push(item);
    }
    public bool IsEmpty
    {
        get { return _head.Next == null && _head.IsEmpty; }
    }
}
public static BigInteger Ackermann(BigInteger m, BigInteger n)
{
    var stack = new OverflowlessStack<BigInteger>();
    stack.Push(m);
    while(!stack.IsEmpty)
    {
        m = stack.Pop();
    skipStack:
        if(m == 0)
            n = n + 1;
        else if(m == 1)
            n = n + 2;
        else if(m == 2)
            n = n * 2 + 3;
        else if(n == 0)
        {
            --m;
            n = 1;
            goto skipStack;
        }
        else
        {
            stack.Push(m - 1);
            --n;
            goto skipStack;
        }
    }
    return n;
}
```

Again, calling `Ackermann(4, 2)` returns:

[image]

Which is the correct result. The stack structure used will never throw, so the only limit remaining is the heap (and time of course, with large enough inputs you'll have to use "universe lifetime" as a unit of measurement...).

Since the way it's used is analogous to the tape of a Turing machine, we're reminded of the thesis that any calculable function can be calculated on a Turing machine of sufficient size.

Comment: But you are still using a stack, it's just not the built in stack. The question is about avoiding to overflow the stack, not to avoid the `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: You are using it as a stack. It doesn't matter what you call it or how you are implementing it, you are still replacing one stack with another just to avoid the built in stack.

Comment: You are contradicting yourself. Your solution doesn't solve the problem of overflowing the stack, it only allows for slightly higher input values. It will still overflow, as you say yourself in the answer, and then contradict when trying to make your solution sound better than it is.

Comment: You are missing the point. You are just replacing one kind of stack with another, but it can still overflow. If the goal was just to avoid the `StackOverflowException` you could just replace the code with `throw new ApplicationException();`, and the problem is solved.

Comment: plus 1 for "we don't have to worry about velociraptors or Dijkstra"

Answer (score 1):

Use memoization. Something like:

```
private static Dictionary<int, int> a = new Dictionary<int, int>();

private static int Pack(int m, int n) {
 return m * 1000 + n;
}

private static int Ackermann(int m, int n) {
  int x;
  if (!a.TryGetValue(Pack(m, n), out x)) {
    if (m == 0) {
      x = n + 1;
    } else if (m > 0 && n == 0) {
      x = Ackermann(m - 1, 1);
    } else if (m > 0 && n > 0) {
      x = Ackermann(m - 1, Ackermann(m, n - 1));
    } else {
      x = -1;
    }
    a[Pack(m, n)] = x;
  }
  return x;
}
```

However, this example only shows the concept, it will still not give the correct result for Ackermann(4, 2), as an `int` is way too small to hold the result. You would need an integer with 65536 bits instead of 32 for that.

Comment: @JonHanna: Better change this then... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function

Answer (score 0):

After some screwing around I'd like to summarize the solution approaches:

1. transform recursive to iterative (see Jon's answer)
2. Memoization (see Guffa)
3. use algebraic equivalences such as the special cases of m == 1, m == 2 and m == 3. (see Jon's solution and my comments below here)
4. Simply increase the stack size.

For my Java attempt increasing the size of your stack was an easy solution.
[Is there a way to increase the stack size in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584224/is-there-a-way-to-increase-the-stack-size-in-c)
I don't know if the link above is the right way to do it in c# but perhaps it helps.

Using algebraic equivalences was by far the most dramatic optimization for this specific problem.

**Ackermann ramblings:**

Myself I have been dabbling with the recursive Ackermann's function in Java.
I didn't try Jon's genius approach but stuck to the simple implementation with the -Xss and -Xmx set to irresponsible value.

This made it possible to run Ackermann(4,1) where at first my program couldn't.

Ackermann(4,1) takes about 10 seconds and Ackerman(3,14) about 40 seconds.
Ackermann(4,2) is currently running but it will never finish because of 2 things:

1. I didn't use big-integers so it will hit INTMAX.
2. Ackermann(4,2) = Ackermann(3,Ackermann(4,1)) = Ackermann(3,65533). Since Ackerman(3,n) has been quadrupling in run-time every time I increase n by one it will be quadrupled another 65k times which brings us into "universe lifetime" territory. This really makes me wonder how Jon's optimization works so well. (if Java and c# are even comparable like this?)

Update:
The m == 1 and m == 2 "cheat" by Jon has a dramatic effect and makes Ackermann(4,2) finish in 277ms in my recursive Java implementation.

Comment: I have added an extra case:
else if(m == 3) return (int)Math.pow(2,(n+3))-3;
(actual implementation in Java BigInteger looks much much different)
Interestingly this makes the program crazy fast but it doesnt actually help that much in a weird way.
Ackermann(4,2) is done in 5ms using this implementation and all Ackermann(3,n) calculations are crazy fast. Ackerman(4,3) is never computable since it goes beyond BigInteger's max size or any form of storage in this universe.

Comment: Using this m==3 cheat all recursion is gone for all Ackermann(3,n) cases so this optimization is no longer about Ackermann but about big integers and efficient pow-functions. Ackermann(3,1073741820) ran for 69seconds and I am not sure if the result is correct since I have no reference. However Ackermann(4,2) seemed correct when comparing to other sources.