Convert nested recursive algorithm (Ackermann's function) to iterative algorithm
I came across a practice problem:

I already wrote out the pseudocode for this, really easily too, just made the calls to the function as mention in the problem statement. But I was really struggling with the iterative algorithm for this. Then I came across Converting recursive algorithm to iterative, which gave me an idea.
What if I created a matrix of size (m+1) X (n+1) and solved it top-down using the m,n combinations to evaluate and store the result in the matrix instead of trying to simulate the call stack using complicated logics and stacks?
Will that work? Or is there an easier way to do this?
Also it would be great if anyone could point me to a decent resource that teaches how to convert given recursive algorithms to iterative ones, including this kind of nested recursions.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12188327/1462295

A general recursive function is more or less analogous to a while loop (there are some technicalities about the precise definition). A primitive recursive algorithm is more or less analogous to a for loop. It depends on the algorithm you are trying to implement, but can implement the algorithm in a loop. For example (more Ackermann) https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/157793/71105

The idea of the matrix is an approach that is used for other problems as well, as it is in fact the tabulation aspect of dynamic programming.
But a matrix of (+1)×(+1) will not be enough here because of the third case in the Ackermann definition you presented: it gets its second argument from a recursively retrieved Ackermann number, and that number could be much greater than the given value of . Thus your matrix will soon be too narrow: the number of rows is fine, but the number of columns will be lacking.
You could adapt this idea to make your matrix grow horizontally as is needed while populating it. But as Ackermann values grow very quickly, this would soon lead to memory allocation problems.
Still, if you want to test this idea for small Ackermann values, then here is an implementation of that idea in Python:
def ackermann(a, b):
    dp = [[] for _ in range(a+1)]
    
    m = 0
    while len(dp[a]) <= b:  # while we don't have the wanted result yet...
        n = len(dp[m])  # try to get the Ackermann value for the next n for the given m.
        if m == 0:
            n += 1  # first case: this is the Ackermann value
        else:
            n = dp[m][n-1] if n else 1  # second or third case
            if len(dp[m-1]) <= n:  # if we don't have the recursive value yet...
                m -= 1  # go back and solve a simpler case first
                continue
            n = dp[m-1][n]  # we have the needed recursive value
        dp[m].append(n)  # ...store it. 
        if m < a:  # try to get a value for a larger m (if needed)
            m += 1
    return dp[a][b]

The matrix starts with  dynamically sized rows that are empty at the start, but get extended during the process. The idea is that we attempt to calculate the next horizontal slot for a given row (). If there is a dependency that we have not calculated yet, we reduce  and repeat the attempt until it works out. When it works out, we can increase  again, ...etc.
As said before, this will only work for small Ackermann numbers. See this demo:
for m in range(4):
    for n in range(11):
        ack = ackermann(m, n)
        print(ack, end=" ")
    print()

This prints:
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 
2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 
3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 
5 13 29 61 125 253 509 1021 2045 4093 8189 

Avoiding the matrix
The values from the matrix that are actually used for a next calculation, are always the last values in a row. So we could save on space by only keeping the last value we have for each row, and the length that row would have had. This reduces the memory used to just O().
Here is the above script adapted with that idea. It produces the same output:
def ackermann(a, b):
    dp_n = [0] * (a+1)  # the sizes of each row in the matrix
    dp_ack = [1] * (a+1)  # the rightmost value in each row of the matrix
    
    m = 0
    while dp_n[a] <= b:  # while we don't have the wanted result yet...
        n = dp_n[m]  # try to get the Ackermann value for the next n for the given m.
        if m == 0:
            n += 1  # first case: this is the Ackermann value
        else:
            n = dp_ack[m]  # second or third case
            if dp_n[m-1] <= n:  # if we don't have the recursive value yet...
                m -= 1  # go back and solve a simpler case first
                continue
            n = dp_ack[m-1]  # we have the needed recursive value
        dp_ack[m] = n  # ...store it.
        dp_n[m] += 1
        if m < a:  # try to get a value for a larger m (if needed)
            m += 1
    return dp_ack[a]

